# Can i select two table in one query?

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 table

1. fees
2. additional_fees

**fees**

```
fees id | fees_name | department | semester | hall_ticket | amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------
      1 |Tution Fees|    CSE     |    2-1   |     1234    | 10000
```

**additional fees**

```
fees id | fees_name | department | semester | add.amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------
      9 | Exam Fees |    CSE     |   2-1    | 5000
```

i want like this

```
 fees_name | department | semester | hall_ticket | amount
---------------------------------------------------------
Tution Fees|    CSE     |    2-1   |     1234    | 10000
 Exam Fees |    CSE     |    2-1   |             | 5000
```

Is this posible to get the result like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION`

```
select fees id , fees_name , department , semester , hall_ticket, amount from fees
union 
select fees id , fees_name , department , semester , null, add.amount from additionalfees
```

Answer (score 1):

use union all

```
select fees_id,fees_name,department,semester,hall_ticket,amount from fees
union all
select fees_id,fees_name,department,semester,null,add.amount from additional_fees
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the function UNION.

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is

```
  SELECT * FROM table1, table2;
```